# SQL Service Broker External Activator not launching exe

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, service-broker

I need to get SSB External Activation to launch an exe off of a db trigger. With the bits of information available on the net I have managed to get almost everything working perfectly. I can send messages to the queue and I can read messages off the queue using a C# app that continuously polls the db. But I need the External Activator to actually launch my exe. This is for work and I'm stuck so any help is greatly appreciated!

External Activator Log file: [Here](https://dev.alinity.com/CMTO/WebClient/External/EATrace.zip)

External Activator Config file: [Here](https://dev.alinity.com/CMTO/WebClient/External/EAService.zip)

Status' of Queues (picture): [Here](https://dev.alinity.com/CMTO/WebClient/External/Capture.jpg)

Thanks!

Edit: SQL Code:

ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2012 SET ENABLE_BROKER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;

CREATE MESSAGE TYPE [requestMessageType]
VALIDATION = WELL_FORMED_XML

CREATE MESSAGE TYPE [responseMessageType]
    VALIDATION = WELL_FORMED_XML

CREATE CONTRACT [smtContract]
(
[requestMessageType] SENT BY INITIATOR,
[responseMessageType] SENT BY TARGET
)

CREATE QUEUE InitiatorQueue
WITH STATUS = ON

CREATE QUEUE TargetQueue
WITH STATUS = ON

CREATE SERVICE InitiatorService
ON QUEUE InitiatorQueue 
(
    [smtContract]
)

CREATE SERVICE TargetService
ON QUEUE TargetQueue
(
    [smtContract]
)

CREATE QUEUE ExternalActivatorQueue 
WITH STATUS = ON

CREATE SERVICE ExternalActivatorService
ON QUEUE ExternalActivatorQueue
(
    [http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/PostEventNotification]
)

CREATE EVENT NOTIFICATION EventNotificationTargetQueue 
    ON QUEUE TargetQueue
    FOR QUEUE_ACTIVATION
    TO SERVICE 'ExternalActivatorService', 'current database';

CREATE TABLE [Order]
(
    ID int identity(1000,1) NOT NULL,
    Amount MONEY NOT NULL
)

-- Trigger will add a message into a ImportQueue
Create TRIGGER OnOrderInserted ON [Order] FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN 
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
        DECLARE @ch UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
        DECLARE @messageBody NVARCHAR(MAX);

```
    BEGIN DIALOG CONVERSATION @ch
            FROM SERVICE [InitiatorService]
            TO SERVICE 'TargetService'
            ON CONTRACT [smtContract]
            WITH ENCRYPTION = OFF;

    -- Construct the request message
    SET @messageBody = (SELECT ID, Amount FROM [Order] FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS);

    -- Send the message to the TargetService
    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION @ch
    MESSAGE TYPE [requestMessageType] (@messageBody);
COMMIT;
```

END 
GO

alter authorization on database::AdventureWorks2012 to [sa];

ALTER QUEUE InitiatorQueue
WITH ACTIVATION 
(
    PROCEDURE_NAME = ProcessResponseMessages,
    STATUS = ON,
    MAX_QUEUE_READERS = 1,
    EXECUTE AS OWNER
)

Comment: For anyone having the same issue, it turned out to be a security issue plus don't forget you need to manually start the EA windows service. (also, the credentials you give that service will be the ones used to query db), this was a tough one, best of luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be very careful on forming the message and sending it to the queue as well as win-service configuration has to be set properly.

Check the post here : [No enabled application monitor is on behalf of queue XYZ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359859/no-enabled-application-monitor-is-on-behalf-of-queue-xyz?answertab=votes#tab-top)