# Let a WCF service know that a SQL Server Service Broker message has arrived

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2012, service-broker

I am looking into moving from NServiceBus to SQL Server Service Broker.

The one piece I am missing is the "Raise Event" section.  When a message arrives for NServiceBus, it raises an event in my code.  This has worked great.

For SQL Server Message Broker, I can think of two ways to do this:

- Create a CLR sproc to have my SQL Server call my WCF Service
- Have my WCF Service continually poll the database to see if there are new messages.

  - This can have timeout issues in WCF.

I have tried the second option with other apps (not Service Broker apps) and it worked poorly.

I like the first one best, but is seems very unconventional to me.

Before I start coding it I thought I would ask if I am missing the big picture here.  How do other apps do this with SQL Server Service Broker?

NOTE: I currently process about 1/2 million messages a day with my NServiceBus Solution.  I need my solution to be robust enough to deal with that kind of through put.

Answer (score 3):

With SQL Server Service Broker you do not need to poll. The `WAITFOR (RECEIVE ...)` construct is non-polling and blocks until a message is available for processing (not just 'arrived', it also consider [correlated locking](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171615%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)). Service Broker also uses [internal activation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171601%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) which eliminates the need for an external service completely and automatically runs your code on-demand. For the record, I know systems that use Service Broker and activation to process 1/2 million messages per **minute**.

But is unclear how all this integrate with WCF. If both your endpoints are SQL Server instances that communicate using SQL Server Service Broker then there is not much room for WCF.

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious - what made you decide to move away from NServiceBus?

Also, have you looked at possibly using the SQL Server transport (new in v4) for handling this integration scenario? Finally, I'd suggest looking at this thread from the discussion group for some pointers:

http://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/nservicebus/conversations/topics/17931

Comment: We have used NServiceBus for a year and like it.  However, our messaging stream is linear.  (Sproc->Message DB->Pull Message Groups To Distributor Queue->Distributor Queue->Distributor->Worker Queues->Worker)  I have started calling it our "Christmas Light Steam" because if one queue goes out then it all goes out (though not as much for the workers).  
We find ourselves checking each queue/process to find out where the process died.  I have thought it over and a Bus seems better suited to a scenario where a Queue can go down and the rest of the system can keep working.

Comment: Since our whole system goes down when one queue goes down, we are getting the worst of both worlds.  (We have multiple points of failure that cause downtime and many points to check to get back up.  We want to move to a Broker because then if things go down, there is one point of failure to fix.)  With a Broker my stream goes like this Sproc->Broker Queue -> Activator->Workers.  And the only point that is actually moving data (or storing it) is the Broker Queue.  Also, the broker queue can better support the grouping of messages for me.

Comment: (If you are curious you can see this NServiceBus discussion group thread for more info about the grouping issues I had: http://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/nservicebus/conversations/messages/13607)

Comment: Just so you know, in version 4 of NServiceBus you can run in a broker architecture as well - whether that's using ActiveMQ, RabbitMQ, or even SQL Server tables.

Comment: So, when you say "No Simpler" you mean it.  NServiceBus is hard, but Sql Server Service Broker is harder.  Quite a bit harder.  My foray into ssb has me heading back to NServiceBus.

Answer (score 1):

How about [Service Broker External Activator](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/36a58004-dbef-46ad-85a2-93563f3f8f0e/announcing-service-broker-external-activator)? If you want to try it out then the approach will be...,

1. Create an EXE, console I will prefer or Windows but better to make command line enabled.
2. Create actual message queue and push the message as soon as the external activation queue filled with message.
   *The reason to create separate queue because with provided solution from Microsoft its not possible to pass message to other application with command line, if we get source code from MS then it will become good enhancement and complete solution.*

**How it will work...?**

1. Windows Service is continuously polling the external activation
   queue, one message is received it will execute the EXE [specified in service config].
2. Immediately message will be purged from external activation queue, and executed application will make call to WCF service.
3. WCF service will read the actual message queued and start its processes.
4. Make the WCF call async so that initiator exe will not last long [choice with you if you need async or not]

Note : You have to be careful with setting [configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359859/no-enabled-application-monitor-is-on-behalf-of-queue-xyz?answertab=votes#tab-top) of external activation windows service.

Without Service Bus this is the only effective solution, and we did use it.